# Validate multi level body with express validator

Tags: node.js, express

I've this body data:

```
{
    "type" : "cfe",
    "products": [
        {
            "key" : 123
        }
    ]
}
```

To validate multi levels, for example, type must be "cfe" or "literal" and products must be an array I must create a custom validator or express support multi level validator?